# Flutter Test for API Helper class using Dio

Tags: flutter, dart, testing, dio

I am using a helper class to make request to server for that I am using `Dio`.
I want to test the helper class
this is my helper class

```
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';

import '../error/exceptions.dart';

enum HttpMethod { GET, POST, PUT, DELETE }

abstract class ApiClient {
  Future<Response> request(
    HttpMethod method,
    String path, {
    Map<String, dynamic>? headers,
    Map<String, dynamic>? queryParams,
    dynamic body,
  });
}

/// This class provides http calls using dio package
class ApiClientImpl implements ApiClient {
  final Dio dio;

  ApiClientImpl({required this.dio});

  @override
  Future<Response> request(
    HttpMethod method,
    String path, {
    Map<String, dynamic>? headers,
    Map<String, dynamic>? queryParams,
    dynamic body,
  }) async {
    // we can add headers here which are common for every restapi call
    // headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'};

    try {
      final _response = await dio.request(
        path,
        options: Options(
          method: _getApiMethodString(method),
          headers: headers,
        ),
        queryParameters: queryParams,
        data: body,
      );
      return _response;
    } on DioError {
      throw FetchDataException('Dio Error Occurred');
    }
  }

  String _getApiMethodString(HttpMethod method) {
    switch (method) {
      case HttpMethod.GET:
        return 'GET';
      case HttpMethod.POST:
        return 'POST';
      case HttpMethod.PUT:
        return 'PUT';
      case HttpMethod.DELETE:
        return 'DELETE';
    }
  }
}
```

The test I wrote for it is

```
@GenerateMocks([Dio])
void main() {
  late MockDio dio;
  late ApiClientImpl apiClient;

  setUp(() {
    dio = MockDio();
    apiClient = ApiClientImpl(dio: dio);
  });

  group('ApiService class methods test', () {
    test('Should return response when request to server is made', () async {
      // arrange
      var successMessage = {'message': 'Success'};
      const baseUrl = 'https://example.com/';
      final options = Options(method: 'GET', headers: null);

      when(dio.request(baseUrl,
              options: options, queryParameters: anyNamed('queryParameters')))
          .thenAnswer((_) async => Response(
              requestOptions: RequestOptions(path: baseUrl),
              data: successMessage,
              statusCode: 200));

      // act
      final response = await apiClient.request(HttpMethod.GET, baseUrl);

      // assert
      expect(response.data, successMessage);
    });
  });
}
```

I am getting an error

```
MissingStubError: 'request'
No stub was found which matches the arguments of this method call:
request('https://example.com/', {data: null, queryParameters: null, cancelToken: null, options: Instance of 'Options', onSendProgress: null, onReceiveProgress: null})
```

How Can I write a correct test for the helper class.